# What is the difference for installing Nginx with the official repository and Ubuntu repository?

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, repository, nginx

I need to install Nginx on my server. I see that it is possible to install it with :

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

or with :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hda-me/nginx-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

What is the difference for installing Nginx with the official repository and Ubuntu repository?

Which method is recommended

Comment: Most likely you will find no difference other than the PPA getting new versions faster.

Comment: @tropcool; PPA's are 3rd party, so you have to trust the source, and monitor if the owner/team is still supporting it, or it just ended support at any time.  The Ubuntu repositories are guaranteed to be supported for the length of time mentioned at release (ie. 5 years for 'main' for LTS for security updates; even if not any new versions, shorter if from other repos or non-lts).  PPA's offer no guarantee so you need to do the validation yourself.   (*this advice is general, and applies to any PPA or 3rd party source, not your specific source*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no significant difference, however:

Installing packages from Ubuntu repository in some cases is safer and solid, because you stick with something that was well tested for your distribution, before being distributed. It will be also properly handled during dist-upgrades.

> Which method is recommended

It's always recommended to use official Ubuntu repositories when it's possible. Any custom repository may cause problems or incompatibilities at some point.

When it comes to nginx instead of using custom PPA it's better to add official nginx repository. You can find instruction here: https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu

Comment: Note that this PPA is **not** owned by the "folks behind nginx", so this is not an official Nginx PPA.

Comment: @MestreLion fair point, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

before install on production server try first to install nginx in virtual machine with similar OS if the test is ok then apply it in your server.

I recommend for you to install nginx from its official repository(build from source, search for documentation how to build nginx from source), because is update and with new features and performances than the old version on Ubuntu repository.